# Derivation of Gamma distribution characteristic function reference?

Tags: probability-theory, gamma-function, characteristic-functions

I was wondering if there was a derivation of the Gamma distribution characteristic function without expanding the $e^{itx}$ into an infinite summation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2949892/321264