# Finding a characteristic function for a Gamma random variable

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function, characteristic-functions

I have the following PDF:
$$f(x)=xe^{-x}$$
for x>0. I am to find the characteristic equation for this PDF.
I have so far:
$$\phi(u)=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x+iux}dx= \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{x(iu-1)}dx $$
Through integration by parts I now have
$$\phi(u)=\frac{xe^{x(iu-1)}}{iu-1}\Big|_0^{\infty}-\frac{e^{x(iu-1)}}{(iu-1)^2}\Big|_0^{\infty}$$
Since the integral contains imaginary parts I am confused as to how to continue solving. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PDF means probability density function ? how can it be negative ? check it for $x<0$

Comment: sorry the problem defines x>0

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: Does complex number not play a part when integrating? currently integrating by parts.

Comment: It is a complex function.  You will get a much better result if you make the exponent in the last line $-x(1-iu)$ so $\phi(u)=\frac{1}{(1-iu)^2}$.

Comment: I think I understand how to solve it now. Thank you everyone

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2949892/321264