# Deriving the characteristic function of the Pareto distribution

Tags: gamma-function, characteristic-functions

For the [Pareto probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), with density function

$$f(x ; x_m, \alpha) = \begin{cases}
0 & \qquad  \text{for $x \leq 0$}  \\ \alpha \frac{x_m^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} & \qquad  \text{for $x > x_m$} \end{cases}$$

we have the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory))

$$ \varphi(t) = \alpha (-ix_mt)^\alpha \Gamma(-\alpha,-ix_mt)$$

with $\Gamma(s,x)$ the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). (this is according to the Wikipedia page and [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pareto%20distribution%20characteristic%20function))

**How can I derive this?**

I have tried the following steps

$$\begin{array}{}
\varphi(t) =  E[e^{itX}] &=&  \int_{x_m}^\infty \frac{\alpha x_m^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} e^{itx} \,dx \\
&=& \alpha x_m^\alpha \int_{x_m}^\infty x^{-\alpha-1}  e^{itx} \,dx \\
&=& \alpha (-i x_m t)^{\alpha} \int_{x_m}^\infty  (-itx)^{-\alpha-1}  e^{itx} \,(-it)dx 
\end{array}$$
This implies the following

$$ \int_{x_m}^\infty  (-itx)^{-\alpha-1}  e^{itx} \,(-it)dx  = \Gamma(-\alpha,-ix_mt)$$

That is where I get stuck. How can I prove that step? I know that for positive and real $s$ and $x$ we have $\int_x^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x}\, dx = \Gamma(s,x)$, but in the case above we have negative and imaginary coefficients.

---

Edit: I found an article deriving the related Laplace transform for a shifted Pareto distribution (Nadarajah and Kotz 2006 [Queueing Systems 54(4):243-244](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11134-006-0299-1)). However, it does not explain the step where I get stuck.

They use the following steps:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
E[e^{-sX}] &=& &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ab^a e^{-sx}}{(b+x)^{a+1}} \,dx \\
&=& a(bs)^a e^{bs}& \int_{bs}^{\infty} u^{-a-1} e^{-u} \,du  \qquad \text{substituting $u=b+x$} \\
& = & a(bs)^a e^{bs} &\Gamma(-a,bs)
\end{array}$$

Is the last step, changing the integral into a Gamma function, valid for negative $-a$? Can I substitute $s$ with $s = -it$, to get the characteristic function from this Laplace transform?

Comment: I guess I might use a path integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Integral_representation besides the regular definition of the incomplete gamma function

Comment: With that path integral representation I could rewrite the integral as $$\int_{x_m}^\infty  (-itx)^{-\alpha-1}  e^{itx} \,(-it)dx  = - \int_{x = -i \infty t}^{x = -ix_mt}  x^{-\alpha-1}  e^{-x} \,dx =  \gamma(-\alpha, -i\infty)- \gamma(-\alpha,-itx_m)$$ But how should I handle the infinity here, and is this equal to $$ \gamma(-\alpha, -i\infty)- \gamma(-\alpha,-i x_m t) = \Gamma(-\alpha, -ix_mt) \quad ?$$

Comment: related is the characteristic function of the gamma distribution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949892